# Changing the size of the split screen in vimdiff

Tags: vim

I only know two commands for dealing with vimdiff:

`Ctrl-w Ctrl-w` switches windows and `Ctrl-w =` makes the two windows equal width if they became uneven due to, for example, resizing the terminal.

How can I make the left screen much larger than the right, for instance?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use any windowing command in `vimdiff`, for example <kbd>CTRL-w <</kbd> to make the left window one column smaller. This can also be combined with a count, for example <kbd>CTRL-W 5></kbd> to make the right window 5 columns smaller. Consult the help page with `:help CTRL-w` to get a list of window commands.

Additionally, you can use the mouse to change the size of the windows by clicking the boundary between both windows and dragging it into a direction. You might have to enable mouse support by issuing `:set mouse=a` first.

Comment: and the student was enlightened.

Comment: Wow! great info. I've long thought not being able to adjust the left,right window size in vimdiff is inconvenient and what I have to live with. Now it'll be much convinient. Thanks!

Comment: and if you want to disable this mouse activation, do 'set mouse-=a'. this way you can do copy-paste as you did before.(otherwise the paste occurs at current mouse position). you can switch between the two modes.